# How to find an element inside a tablelayout using xpath in appium for android

Tags: java, android, selenium, xpath, appium

How to find an element inside a tablelayout using xpath in appium for android. I have tried the following syntax

```
WebElement username=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TableLayout[@index='1']//android.widget.TableRow[@index='0']/android.widget.EditText[@index='0']"));

username.sendKeys("sampletext");
```

but I am getting the following exception.

```
"org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."
```

When I tried the following

```
WebElement username=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='0']"));
```

It is working fine. The problem arises when I tried to add the parent followed by the child.

1.How can i access all the childs of table layout using a for loop?

2.How can I find a child followed by parent using xpath.Pls help

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
WebElement username=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//TableLayout[@index='1']/TableRow[@index='0']/EditText[@index='0']"));
```